# ¿Como puedo tomar el valor de un textarea y que al almacenarlo en una variable, respete los saltos de lineas y espacios del textarea?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un apartado para notas rápidas pero al guardarlas en un archivo (`.txt`) me guarda el valor del textarea en una sola linea y quiero que se respete los saltos de linea y los espacios;

Ejemplo:

Valor o texto que ingreso al textarea:

> HOLA MUNDO
>   HOLA MUNDO
>   HOLA MUNDO
>   HOLA MUNDO

Valor que guarda en el archivo (.txt):

> HOLAMUNDOHOLAMUNDOHOLAMUNDOHOLAMUNDO

**Código HTML**

```
<textarea placeholder="Escribir..." 
          id="input_textarea" 
          style="width: 370px; 
                 height: 150px; 
                 margin-top: 25px; 
                 margin-left: 16px; 
                 margin-right: 16px;">
</textarea>
```

**Código JavaScript**

```
function guardar_notas_txt()
    { 
        var textToWrite = input_textarea.value;
        var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
        var file_name = nombre_guardado_notas.value;
        var fileNameToSaveAs = file_name+".txt";
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = "My Hidden Link";
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
    }

function destroyClickedElement(event)
    {
        document.body.removeChild(event.target);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esta función regex al momento de capturar el valor de tu `textarea`:

```
var textToWrite = input_textarea.value.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");
```

Demo:

```js
function guardar_notas_txt() {

  var textToWrite = input_textarea.value.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  var file_name = "archivo";
  var fileNameToSaveAs = file_name + ".txt";
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "My Hidden Link";
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Escribir..." id="input_textarea" style="width: 370px; 
                 height: 150px; 
                 margin-top: 25px; 
                 margin-left: 16px; 
                 margin-right: 16px;">
</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="guardar_notas_txt();">Guardar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, era lo que buscaba 8)